# How much NCR infamy do I gain from arming ARCHIMEDES?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

According to [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Lucky_Old_Sun), arming ARCHIMEDES will kill all the NCR troops stationed at HELIOS-I. While that is a regrettable consequence, I really (*really*) want Euclid's C-Finder.

So when this awe-inspiring weapon goes off, exactly how much NCR infamy am I going to gain? I want to know where my rep with them will stand after the fact. I am currently Liked. I'm OK (I think) with going down to Neutral, but I don't want the NCR to become hostile to me. Yet.

Anyone with GECK access have a good answer on this? (And I don't want to use the glitch involving fast travel, since I want to see the show!)

(Will wearing, say, a Legion or Powder Gangers disguise avoid the infamy?)

Comment: "*I really (really) want Euclid's C-Finder*". [Won't it be better to *not* arm the ARCHIMEDES I, and avoid NCR infamy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/11769/4797) (You can still use Euclid's C-Finder.)

Comment: @galacticninja: by the time that (admittedly, more peaceful and less explody) answer was posted, the damage (so to speak) was long done. The answer I accepted did work for me, on the day I needed it, in the play style I was employeeing for that character. YMMV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wearing a disguise *will* avoid the infamy. Toss on your finest toga, yell out your loudest "AVE CAESAR!" and let toast those NCR pigs.

I can smell the bacon from here.

Comment: Negative. Upon returning to HELIOS One no longer in my Legion outfit, the NCR started blasting on me anyway. :( Maybe I need to remain in the Legion outfit and wipe out the rest manually?

Comment: Well yeah, because you took a directly hostile action towards them. You should never need to go back to Helios One though -  more importantly, how do the NCR folks react at Forlorn Hope, Golf, McCarran, or Mojave Outpost (to name a few examples).

Comment: They were OK. I wanted to go back to loot the corpses. So I solved this problem by fast traveling from the tower to HELIOS One directly, and melted everyone left down manually. Then I looted everyone. Took off my Legion Outfit, and I'm a "smiling troublemaker" with NCR & The Strip (I guess for not giving them power), and everyone else is unaffected. SCORE! (And thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

You can have access to the laser without killing the NCR at Helios One. When you configure the power grid, you can select from several different grid configurations, including one named "Archimedes II". Selecting this option arms the orbital laser for your use. Independent of which configuration you choose, you can also select the option "Arm Archimedes plant defense system". It is this second choice which kills all the NCR at Helios One.

Just choose "Archimedes II" for power output, and don't choose to arm the plant defenses, and then you can have your awesome orbital laser.