# Why did ARCHIMEDES not activate?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Following this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/how-much-ncr-infamy-do-i-gain-from-arming-archimedes)...

So I armed the ARCHIMEDES system, hoping to see all those NCR scum get fried...according to the Wiki it is a sight to behold.

However, I went through and armed everything, went up to the top of the tower and was blinded by the array adjusting itself, and....nothing.

I had to go and kill all the NCR troops myself.  What did I miss?

Comment: Do you follow Caesar, House, or the Yes Man? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making sure, but [according to the wiki, I quote](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Lucky_Old_Sun#Time_to_flip_the_switch):

> The terminal on the mainframe contains some notes the player has
> probably already seen on previous terminals in the building, and an
> option Configure Power Grid. Selecting it reveals 5 options:
>
> ...
>
> 5 Full region (emergency output level): This solution overloads the plant, which prevents Archimedes I from being activated (see further
> notes). This gains no reputation with any faction, but Ignacio Rivas
> will still give the player some rewards.
>
> ...
>
> If the player has chosen to activate the Archimedes I defense system,
> and has chosen option 5 (overload) for the power grid, horns will
> blare and a warning will play about the imminent weapon test, but
> shortly thereafter everything grinds to a halt. If the player is
> trusted by Ignacio Rivas, they can now go talk to him to receive
> awards. Otherwise the quest ends.

You did not do this, right?

**Edit:** Further down that page:

> Bugs
>
> ...
>
> - pc The Archimedes I sequence may not play out even though activated at the mainframe.

You could have run into that.

Comment: Hmm, no.  I distributed power evenly throughout the world, but still activated Archimedes so that I could make use of it later.  I thought that activating it still fired the initial burst.

Comment: Boo....that might be quite disappointing then.